View Query Definitions for MS Access Databases via DBeaver
I am attempting to connect to an MS Access database via DBeaver and wanted to know if there is a way to view the SQL code behind my Access queries. I have hundreds of SQL codes so it would be a hassle to manually copy them and update them.
MS Access: Access 2007 - 2016 File Format
DBeaver Enterprise 24.0.0
Driver: Modern JDBC-ODBC bridge
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise v. 22H2
When I have a view open in DBeaver and click definition, I get the following message: -- View definition not available;
I have also tried right-clicking a view > clicking Generate SQL > and clicking DDL and still get the same error message:  -- View definition not available;
I saw that some people have tried implementing manual queries with the hidden system tables, but when I try to do so, I get the following message: SQL Error [42000]: [-1907][42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.
Side note, I have also tried using the UCanAccess Driver to connect to my database and this did not let me connect to the database at all. The connection would take forever then the program would eventually crash.
